# Opening Realm file in browser always requires an encryption key

Tags: ios, encryption, realm

I'm using Realm Browser 0.9.85 and using the examples in https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.

I'm a total Realm newbie so go easy on me. Every time I try to open up a Realm file from the example from GitHub, I get a request to enter in the encryption key. It seems like the default configuration in Realm is to not have it's db be encrypted, so I don't know what gives. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Which version of the Realm framework are you using?

Comment: The most current version v0.101.0 just pull from  https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa

Comment: https://studio-releases.realm.io/latest/download/mac-dmg That work for me in my new MacbookPro M1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you're opening a file built with Realm 0.101, you'll need to use a version of the Realm Browser that's compatible with those files.

You can get Realm Browser 0.101 from the Mac App Store here: https://itunes.apple.com/app/realm-browser/id1007457278

or as an archive here: https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/0.101.0

This is necessary because Realm 0.101 brought changes to the Realm file format that can't be read by previous versions. Read the release post for more information: https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-0.101.0/

Answer (score 26):

Instead of downloading old versions, Download Realm Studio it will open the file without any required keys.

https://docs.realm.io/sync/realm-studio

Hopefully, it solves your issue.

Comment: "Realm Studio" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Comment: Hello, @TimSim  This happens because your mac setting will not download any strange software from the internet, to solve this, please check this video.                                             https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0V5Phac8pao

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Realm Browser. Now working only with Realm Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file using MongoDB Realm Studio.

I installed v10.1.2 without a problem in MacOS 11.3.1

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/studio/install/

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download MongoDB Realm studio then try
https://studio-releases.realm.io/latest/download/mac-dmg